# Gimp: Change coordinate system (where 0,0 is)

Tags: gimp

I use gimp for manipulating images for my software projects.

I am used to working in a coordinate system where 0,0 is at the bottom left of the screen.

Gimp uses 0,0 as the top left; Is there a setting in Gimp where I can change this, so when I mouse over an image, for example, the coordinate displayed is relative to the bottom left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I dont think there is...

Comment: Looks like I'm going to have to grab the source and hack it in myself then ^_^.